# how to enable trust for chain certs in weblogic or java

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic-10.x

I have an Oracle service Bus domain running on weblogic 10.3.6 with 2 managed servers in cluster.
We have a proxy service deployed on this domain which goes to an external Business service for validating address. This Business Service is listening on SSL port and SSL cert has EntrustCACert>IntermidateCert1>IntermidateCert2>ServerCert

#### Issue: Getting below error during connectivity testing -

General runtime error: [Security:090548]The certificate chain received from ws2.site1.com - 197.109.80.xxx contained a V3 CA certificate which was missing the basic constraints.

#### Solutions i have tried:

1) added JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.security.SSL.enforceConstraints=off " in the startup script and it resolve the issue. But i was told this is not the prefered way and use trust keystore to implement.

2)to implement trust, I copied all the 4 certs in following reverse order EntrustCACert>IntermidateCert1>IntermidateCert2>ServerCert in one file named DSperian.pem and imported in Jrockit cacerts file( /apps/Oracle/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_31-R28.2.3-4.1.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts ) using below command but getting the same above error.
    `keytool -import -alias DSperian -trustcacerts -file DSperian.pem -keystore cacerts`

Question:
Please let me know  if im doing the right way to import cert to create trust. so my OSB domain will blindly trust the Business service ( web-service) and ignore 
the "basic constraints" error. Do i need to utilize weblogic specific trust keystore file but this OSB weblogic is running on non-ssl port ?
are there any other options available ? Asking Business-service to update their cert to include "basic constraints" is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a problem with your certificate.

Security certificates have a set of constraints that allow them to perform certain functions (or restrict them to certain functions).

Have a look at each of the certificates and ensure that they have constraints assigned to them that are suitable for the task.

To get more details on the error enable SSL debugging in your web logic server add the following to your server startup script

```
-Dssl.debug=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true
```

[More information in Configure SSL in WebLogic server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/secmanage/ssl.html)

Use the following command to validate your keystone

```
java utils.ValidateCertChain -jks my key mykeystore
```

Then, whoever provided the root certificate needs to fix up your issues.

Comment: The issue is my weblogic domain (OSB) makes connection to Web-service (Business service in OSB) as client.My weblogic doesnt host the certs.I would like to make changes on my side so that my weblogic trust the web-service. Is cacerts store is the right file to import server side( in my case web-service side ) to establish trust ?

Comment: It is not trust that is the problem.  It is the validity of the root certificate on the server you are trying to access.  The only way you can get around it is to use the first option you listed above unless the server you are communicating with fixes their problem.  The requirement for these basic constraints has been in the specification since 2002 but it was not necessary to implement.  Now most clients are becoming more careful about what they talk with so that is why you are getting the error you are seeing.  Talk to your server owner and see what they can do.